# Review the ER diagram regarding a National Football Team

Tags: relational-theory, relations

> We need to store information pertaining to football players who are or
>   were members of the national team.
>
> For each player we store the following: first name, last name, date of
>   birth, debut date and the nominal position of each player.
>
> With each player is associated information about the history of his
>   performances in matches, namely: date of the match, number of minutes
>   on the field, shot goals, and penalty cards.
>
> Also information of his club carrier is stored. We would like to know
>   which club he played for and for how long.
>
> In our system we also store information concerning matches of the
>   national team. For each match we keep the following information: date,
>   place, result, name of the opponent, name of the main referee, type of
>   a match (friendly, World Cup, European Championship, qualification to
>   WC or EC tournament), and names of players who shot goals.

Please, review my ER diagram.

[image]

Should "Type of match" be a separate entity?

I have included some extra attributes to the entities which were not described in the original description of the case-study.

I have used "Look Across" min-max notation.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the `DateOfMatch` being in `Performance`. Surely it is fine in `Match`, then link the `Performance` to the `Match`

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, hmmm... good point.

Comment: Yes type of match should be seperare entity, since you may need to add another match type such asian tour or australia tour.  It is good to consider the future in modeling for such fields.